# Efficient CSV extraction and allocation

Tags: netlogo

I've tried to find a way to do this more neat/more efficient cause I don't believe that I wouldn't be able to achieve the same result more efficient.

I have a csv file containing data with initial states for my turtles. Each row represents values for turtle-owned variables and each column represents an individual turtle. For each turtle, I would like to initialize his variables. At this moment I'm doing it the following way (which works, but to me looks not efficient):

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; GENERAL PROCEDURES ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

extensions [ csv ]

breed[households household] 

globals ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[
 HH-data
 HHx-list
 HHy-list
 HHsize-list
 HHcolor-list
]

households-own ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
[
  HHx
  HHy
  HHsize
  Hhcolor
]

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; SETUP PROCEDURES ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

to startup ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

set HH-data (csv:from-file "TestHH.csv" ";")
show HH-data
set HHx-list item 0 HH-data
set HHy-list item 1 HH-data
set HHsize-list item 2 HH-data
set HHcolor-list item 3 HH-data
show HHx-list
let numberOfHH length HHx-list
create-households numberOfHH
(
foreach (sort households) HHx-list
  [ [?1 ?2] -> ask ?1
    [
      set xcor ?2
    ]
  ]
)
(
  foreach (sort households) HHy-list
  [ [?1 ?2] -> ask ?1
    [
      set ycor ?2
    ]
  ]
)
(
  foreach (sort households) HHsize-list
  [ [?1 ?2] -> ask ?1
    [
      set HHsize ?2
    ]
  ]
)
(
  foreach (sort households) HHcolor-list
  [ [?1 ?2] -> ask ?1
    [
      set color ?2
    ]
  ]
)
end ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

However, in the global HH-data already all my data is present. How could I extract this and assign the turtle variables to each turtle without having to make all these individual for-each statements. I tried a few things like this:

```
set HH-data (csv:from-file "TestHH.csv" ";")
show HH-data

let numberOfHH length (item 0 HH-data)
create-households numberOfHH

(
  foreach (sort households) HH-data
  [[?1 ?2] -> ask ?1
    [
      set xcor ?2
      set ycor ?2
      set HHsize ?2
      set HHcolor ?2
    ]
  ]
)
```

But then I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

Found out myself, while I was writing this question, how to solve it.
Thought it might be useful to others and thus therefore to still post it.

```
set HH-data (csv:from-file "TestHH.csv" ";")
;;show HH-data

let numberOfHH length (item 0 HH-data)
create-households numberOfHH

(
  foreach (sort households) (item 0 HH-data) (item 1 HH-data) (item 2 HH-data) (item 3 HH-data)
  [[?1 ?2 ?3 ?4 ?5] -> ask ?1
    [
      set xcor ?2
      set ycor ?3
      set HHsize ?4
      set color ?5
    ]
  ]
)
```